# Unable to use MySQL Go Driver in Google App Engine

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, go

I am trying to get my app to connect to local MySQL db. I am importing the necessary packages in a file that defines a function to initialize the connection

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)
```

The `github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql` is only imported once in the project and I believe that means its init is only called once. However, whenever I start my app with `goapp serve` I keep getting

`Register called twice for driver mysql`

I do not know what's causing this. I know where the offending line is but I am not sure how the `Register()` method gets called twice. My suspicion is that, because `goapp` refreshes your app when there is changes, it calls `init()` again and again causing the `Register()` to get called twice.

Anyone has ever seen this behavior before?

Comment: Does it work when using *dev_appserver.py*?

Comment: I just tried it and ran the command `dev_appserver.py .` and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: The offending line i guess is `_ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"` now . When i remove it, the error goes away but I know I need that to be in there.

Answer (score 0):

Your code may be importing two different mysql packages. Are you sure you aren't pulling in some package from elsewhere?

Comment: I think I can be 99.99% sure that I am not calling it twice somewhere else. I have a fiel called store.go and its package is called store. This file's sole duty is to initialize database connection.

Comment: For the reference, here is how another user fixed it: https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/256#issuecomment-48559630

Comment: It seems there is no fix there?